# Selectively delete mostly duplicate records from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table:

```
PRICE_UPDATE
id (int 5, auto-increment, primary, unique)
part_number (varchar 10, non-null)
price (float(10,2), non-null)
```

Some of the `part_number`s are duplicated (1 or more duplicate records). Sometimes with the same price, sometimes with different prices.

**How can I delete all of the duplicate rows based on part_number, leaving either the highest price or just 1 record if the prices were all the same?**

Is this even doable in straight MySQL?

Answer (score 12):

```
DELETE t1
    FROM YourTable t1, YourTable t2
    WHERE t1.part_number = t2.part_number
        AND (t1.price, t1.id) < (t2.price, t2.id)
```

Comment: The OP was also wanting to delete them if the price was the same (leaving one, of course).

Comment: This is almost what the poster wants -- except that if the highest price for a part number is duplicated, then your query will leave all of them. I'd add `or (t1.price = t2.price and t1.id < t2.id)` to remove duplicates

Comment: @JoeStefanelli +1 the simplest way is the easiest way. Well done :D

Comment: Correction needed. It should be as Ian's comment or like this: `AND (t1.price, t1.id) < (t2.price, t2.id)`

Comment: The `AND t1.id <> t2.id AND t1.price <= t2.price` will delete all rows with max price if there are 2 or more of them.

Comment: ypercube's solution ended up working correctly. The original solution deleted all records with a duplicate `part_number` if the `price`s were the same.

Answer (score 2):

From inside, to outside:

1. Selects the ids with the max price per part_number
2. Selects the max id with the max price per part_number
3. Deletes the ids not present in 2.

---

```
delete tablename where id not in (
(select max(id) from tablename a
 inner join
  ( select id, max(price)
    from tablename
    group by part_number ) b on a.id = b.id and a.price = b.price
 group by part_number))
```