# Keep first of duplicate records and delete the rest

Tags: duplicates, sql-delete, ms-access-2003

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913917/selectively-delete-mostly-duplicate-records-from-mysql) does pretty much what I want to accomplish, but my table is more complicated and does not have a primary key. I also don't quite understand the top answer, what the t1 and t2 mean. If this answer can be applicable to me, would appreciate if someone explain the code.

I have several months' tables that contain info on clients and the policies they hold. Every client has a unique policy ID, but they can have multiple policies, resulting in multiple records under the same policy ID. The duplicate records can be completely different or exactly the same in every field.

For my purposes, **I want to keep only one record for each policy ID. Ideally the record kept is the one with the highest Age**, but does not need to if it's too complicated. Note there may be more than one record with the age that is the max for that particular Policy ID, then it doesn't matter which one of those we keep.

I do not plan on creating a primary key because there are some cases when I will be keeping two records under the same policy ID, which I will make the modification to the code myself. I also don't want to create another table because I am working with 10+ tables. Someone suggested using `first()`, but I'm not sure how to incorporate it into a query.

Please let me know if you need any additional information, and thank you for your help in advance!

=========UPDATE #1

Okay, looks like my question was a bit unrealistic, so I will add an **autonumber primary key**. How will I proceed with that?

Comment: You should really consider adding a primary key as it makes it identifying a single record so much easier and would help you deleting dups. Note having a primary key doesn't mean you can't still have dups.

Comment: I think you are going tto have to give in on something. Either you will need to create a new table or you will have to add a unique key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something on these lines:

```
DELETE Policies.*
FROM Policies
WHERE Policies.ID Not In (
   SELECT TOP 1 id
   FROM   policies p
   WHERE  p.policyid = policies.policyid
   ORDER  BY createdate DESC, id )
```

Comment: I tried running the inner bracket `SELECT` statement on its own, and it asked me to enter the parameter value of `Policies.PolicyID`. Can I just confirm that I am understanding your code right? ID = autonumber primary key; Policies = the table; P = Policies table. Wouldn't the second last line always be true then? Also, the inner bracket only outputs one record.

Comment: The idea uses two ids, The Policy ID mentioned in your text that can be duplicated, and ID, which is the new autonumber. The inner bracket outputs one record per policy id, which is what you want to end up with. I tested with a sample table.

Comment: Ohhhh ok my apologies, I just understood the code. I did a test run on one of my tables with 30k records. It seems to work! So, thank you! One last thing though, the query took quite a while to run - is that normal? I'm just worried because one of my tables has 900k records..

Comment: A query like that is not going to be fast. Do you have to do this often?

Comment: Not often, it's a one time thing for a study, but I have 15 tables to do this on, 14 of them are ~35k and one huge one at 900k. I was checking the test query I did - it did most of them right but 2 of the records that should've been removed were still there...couldn't see anything special with the 2 records...