# Removing duplicates in a MS Access database

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access

I was trying to remove duplicates from the table Main.

It looks like this(here in csv form):

```
"Record ID";Status;Placement;Private;Category;Note;Blob
```

for instance

```
14341692;132;2147483647;False;4;"29.12.10 14:17";System.Byte[]
```

Duplicates means, Note is the same. My approach is this:

```
string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Main";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, MemoVerbindung);
OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
_items = new List<string>(); // <-- Add this
while (dr.Read())
{
    if (dr.FieldCount >= 5)
        _items.Add(dr[5].ToString());
}
dr.Close();
progressBar1.Maximum = _items.Count;
for (int a = 0; a < _items.Count; a++)
{
    progressBar1.Value = a;
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Main WHERE Note = '" + _items[a].ToString().Replace("'", "\'") + "'";

    cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, MemoVerbindung);
    dr = null;
    OleDbDataReader dr2 = null;
    try
    {
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        int u = 0;
        if (dr.FieldCount > 1)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                if (u >= 1)
                {
                    string was = "DELETE FROM Main WHERE [Record ID] = " + dr[0];
                    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(was, MemoVerbindung);

                    OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        //MessageBox.Show(reader[0].ToString());
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }
                u++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Übrig");
            }
        }

        dr.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception mm)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(mm.Message);
    }
}
MessageBox.Show("Fertig");
progressBar1.Value = 0;
```

So in the if (u >= 1) section I am trying to leave one version while removing all others. Unfortunately that does not work meaning all entries are removed but the ones raising an error for a reason. What would you change or is there a generally more elegant way?

Comment: Why do you have duplicates in the DB in the first place?

Comment: No, you can. If there were mistakes and now you're fixing them - that's fine. But if your application is creating duplicates and then you're trying to get rid of them - that is just wrong. And why did you edit your comment? I liked the sarcasm :)

Comment: No, you can. My app is not producing those errors.

Comment: Are the records exact duplicates or should you also choose which one you save and which ones to remove? And you're actually deciding whether two rows are a duplicate by the note column, right? Not by the PK.

Comment: Here is a sample query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9912668/access-2003-keep-first-of-duplicate-records-and-delete-the-rest/9915576#9915576

Answer (score 0):

Use this SQL statement to find the duplicates:

```
SELECT First(Main.[Note]) AS [NoteField], Count(Main.[Note]) AS NumberOfDups
FROM Main
GROUP BY Main.[Note]
HAVING (((Count(Main.[Note]))>1));
```

then you can loop through this recordset (grab it as a SnapShot so changes to the underlying data does not change the results)
use `!NoteField` to know which note to find, and `!NumberOfDups` to know how many you have to delete (remove this number - 1)